# How to choose an element from a state space with a specific probability?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of possibilities `[1,2,3,4,5]`

I want to choose one at random but make it so that I can specify the probability of each one e.g.

```
states = [1,2,3,4,5]
probs = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6]
```

so that 1 is chosen with a probability of 10%, 2 with a probability of 10%, etc.